# Comparing dates with null value in trigger in Oracle 10

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I am sorry if I am asking a question which was already answered, but I cannot find any answer on it. I am writing a trigger in Oracle 10, where I compare 2 dates, as numbers, but I have a problem, if the second value is null.

I have two tables: `Herci` (`dat_umr_her:date`) and `filmy` (`rok_vyd:integer`).

The problem is that `dat_umr_her` is sometimes `NULL` and then I cannot insert any new Herec because an application error is raised inside the if statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "XVIKD00"."DATUM_UMRTIA_HEREC" 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
  ON HERCI
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  l_ROK_VYDANIA filmy.ROK_VYD%TYPE;
BEGIN 
  SELECT FILMY.ROK_VYD
    INTO l_ROK_VYDANIA 
    FROM FILMY
   WHERE FILMY.ID_FILM = :new.ID_HEREC;

  IF( extract( year from :new.dat_umr_her ) < l_ROK_VYDANIA )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2009,'Dátumy nie su v správnom časovom slede'); 
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: What would you like to happen when the column is null?

Comment: to insert the values into the table, is is the databse od Films and Actors, and the value dat_umr_her is the date od death of the actor.

Comment: Im not sure if i got this right, but cant you use coalesce with some default value at the comparision? http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where your exact problem is, but there are two basic approaches:

Either use [`nvl`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) or [`coalesce`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php) to replace a NULL value with some default value (in your case probably a date way in the past or in the future.

Or if you want to use it in a comparison you might use [`is null`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/isnull.php)

This might actually be what you need, judging from the comments

```
IF( 
    (:new.dat_umr_her is not null) 
    AND extract( year from :new.dat_umr_her ) < l_ROK_VYDANIA 
)
```

Comment: IF( extract( year from :new.dat_umr_her ) < l_ROK_VYDANIA ) )or ( extract( year from :new.dat_umr_her ) is null) it will raise application erro anywas, won´t it?

Comment: check out the improved version, which will not raise an application error if dat_umr_her IS NULL

Comment: Yes, I is exactly what i needed:) thank you. Can I have just one more qustion? IF i want to insert new Reziser(Director) but I don´t have any film which he has directed, this trigger ends with exception that no data found. Should i isert the film at first? but he foreign key if diector is beeing used in the table film...

Comment: Welcom to stackoverflow. Cool thing over here is: You can ask as many questions as you want. Just make them new questions. If the select goes against a table that can return 0-N entries you'll have problems in the case N>1 as well. Might try MAX or MIN, whatever fits your needs.

Comment: I have thought of writing it like this, but it cannot by compiled

Comment: create or replace 
trigger "XVIKD00"."DATUM_UMRTIA_REZISER" 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
  ON REZISERI
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  l_ROK_VYDANIA filmy.ROK_VYD%TYPE ;
  
BEGIN 
  SELECT FILMY.ROK_VYD
    INTO l_ROK_VYDANIA 
    FROM FILMY
   WHERE (FILMY.ID_REZISER = :new.ID_REZISER) ;
  IF( 
    (:new.dat_umr_rez is not null) and( FILMY.ROK_VYD is not null)
    AND( extract( year from :new.dat_umr_rez ) < l_ROK_VYDANIA) )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2009,'Dátumy nie su v správnom časovom slede'); 
  END IF;
END;

Comment: You are not expecting anybody to try to decipher that, do you? Just ask a new question.